# How to make prop optional when defining Component

Tags: reactjs

How to make prop optional when defining Component?

Data

```
const dynamicFormData = [{
      required: true, // optional
      title: 'Last Name',
      type: 'letter',
      onDeleteClick: () => {console.log('Delete Click')}
    }, {
      title: 'First Name',
      type: 'letter',
      onDeleteClick: () => {console.log('Delete Click')}
    }
]
```

Defining component

```
        {
          dynamicFormData.map(({title, type, required, onDeleteClick}) => (
            <DynamicForm
              required={required} //Error msg here because required can be undefined
              title={title}
              type={type}
              onDeleteClick={onDeleteClick}/>
          ))
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an object and then spread that to pass as props -

```
dynamicFormData.map(({title, type, required, onDeleteClick}) => {
  const props = {
    title,
    type,
    required,
    onDeleteClick,
  };

  return <DynamicForm {...props} />;
}))
```

In the situation where `required` is `undefined`, then it won't ever get passed.